# JQuery - check if all radio buttons are "No"

Tags: jquery

I have some code that creates an arbitrary number of RadioButton Lists. the HTML is

```
<div id="ConfirmCCLChoice" class="ConfirmChoice">
  <span>
    <input class="rbl" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please Select Yes or No" id="rbl" name="Confirm[i].Taken" type="radio" value="true" />
    Accepted
  </span>
  <span>
    <input checked="checked" class="rbl" id="rbl" name="Confirm[i].Taken" type="radio" value="false" />
    Declined
  </span>
</div>
```

where i is an index of the radio button list.

What I need is some javascript or jquery to check if all the radio buttons have been set to "No". At that point, I need to enable a Text Area so that the customer can explain why all answers are no. (That bit is trivial).

What I have so far is this, where I am simply attempting to get the checked value of each group. However, what it is doing is running 2 * for each line, not once. (So I suspect it is running for each button, not each radio button group

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#ConfirmChoice input').change(function () {           
    $(':radio').each(function() { // loop through each radio button
      var nam = $(this).attr('name'); // get the name of its set
      alert($(':radio[name="' + nam + '"]:checked').val());
    });
  });
});
```

So how should I change this so I iterate through each radio button group and alert the value, as opposed to each radio button?

Comment: You might consider checking if any one button is not set to 'no' (much easier with a single, non-iterative JQuery selector) and not doing the thing iff that condition is met...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work. (For one thing, you didn't close out the ready handler. But still doesn't work after that was fixed.) Put it in a jsFiddle.

Comment: The code you are using is wrong, also I added an answer with the right approach, because your approach has the wrong beginning for what you wanna do.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll check it on Tuesday when I get back into the office. I suspect I have several correct solutions, so I'll see which works best for me.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I went with @j08691 solution in the end. (I couldn't quite get yours to work Dominik, else I would have used that one as it was the most self explanatory for anyone that comes after me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the number of checked declined radio buttons against the number of declined radio buttons and enable/disable the textarea based on that:

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $('textarea').prop('disabled', !($('.ConfirmChoice').find('input[value="false"]:checked').length == $('.ConfirmChoice').find('input[value="false"]').length))
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2evz4na5/)**

Answer (score 0):

What about using the checked selector? Like so:

```
 var data = "_a=add" + $.map($("input:radio:checked"), function(elem, idx) {
                    return "&"+ $(elem).attr("name") + "=" + $(elem).val();
                });
```

Should only return those that are checked, and if the result is null/0 then none are checked and all radio buttons = "No"

Answer (score 0):

You would iterate through the checked radios:

```
 $("input:radio:checked").each(function() { // loop through each radio button
        alert($(this).val());
 });
```

I would probably check for at least one "yes" with something like:

```
var all_no = $('input:radio:checked').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == "Yes"; }).length == 0;
```

Or, to set the textarea disabled property:

```
$('textarea').prop('disabled', 
    $('input:radio:checked').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == "Yes"; }).length != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

So be sure to make something like this. Afterwards `everythingTrue` is filled with the value you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var everythingTrue = true;
  $(':radio').each(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    if($that.data('val') !== true) { // Depends on what should be "no"
      everythingTrue = false;
    }
  });
});
```

---

But what I think you really want to have is something like the following lines of code:

What I did there? I just added the above code into a function that triggers every time the user is changing any radio button. If every radio button is checked with `no` the popup can show up (where my command stays).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var everythingTrue = true
    , checkValues = function () {
        $(':radio').each(function() {
          var $that = $(this);
          if($that.data('val') !== true) { // Depends on what should be "no"
            everythingTrue = false;
          }
        });
      };

  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    checkValues();
    if(everythingTrue == false) {
      // Now you can show your popup here why
      // User checked everything with 'no'
    } else {
      // Don't forget to hide it again if
      // something is checked with 'yes'
    }
  })
});
```